# Bootstrap-Tour RTL Popover position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tour

I am using RTL bootstrap CSS 3.3.7 version with Bootstrap-Tour 0.11.0 version.
The popover element doesn't appear close to the appropriate element, but is positioned to the right.
This problem happens only when I use RTL Bootstrap CSS.

This is the code I currently have:

```
var tour = new Tour({
    template : '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"> <div class="arrow"></div> <h3 class="popover-title"></h3> <div class="popover-content"></div> <div class="popover-navigation"> <div class="btn-group"> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-role="prev">&laquo; הקודם</button> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-role="next">הבא &raquo;</button> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-role="pause-resume" data-pause-text="Pause" data-resume-text="Resume">עצור</button> </div> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-role="end">צא מעזרה</button> </div> </div>',
    steps : [{
            element : "#pop1",
            title : "Title of my step",
            content : "Content of my step",
            backdrop : true,
            backdropPadding : 3
        },
        {
            placement : "top",
            element : "#pop2",
            title : "Title of my step",
            content : "Content of my step",
            backdrop : true,
            backdropPadding : 3
        }
    ]
});
```

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/DUKEiLL/z6qzzsjj/

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap-tour doesn't seem to have rtl support for the moment, even if you manage to position the popover in the right way, you'll still have the navigation with keyboard arrows messed (inverted).
I won't recommand using bootstrap-tour in rtl pages